# Tool to generate .htaccess HTTP 301 redirects for site migration

Tags: web-development, apache

I am migrating my website and its domain name to a new Apache server.

We are using this opportunity to shirk a lot of old content that's no longer relevant, and to restructure our information architecture. None of the physical pages will be transferred, so most pages will have different names.

This results in many pages collapsing into one, and in a few cases we want to redirect to another site.

I need to create an `.htaccess` file to handle the HTTP 301 redirects since old bookmarks and links will break on the new server.

I have already created a spreadsheet with a column list of all our old page URLs, and a corresponding column with the URLs to the new page.

What is a good tool to generate the `.htaccess` file with redirect rules from this list?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered this very nifty free online utility:

[**.HtAccess 301 Redirect Generator Tool**](https://websiteadvantage.com.au/HtAccess-301-Redirect-Generator)

It's simple, allows you pass query strings, and even separate your old URL from your new URL list with whatever delimiter you choose (I simply used a comma). You just paste in your list, and click <kbd>GENERATE RULES</kbd>